# Windows 7 and paper wallets

Tags: paper-wallet

I was wondering if BTC cold storage or paper wallets can work with Windows 7 and / or Linux Mint? Please advise. Many thanks indeed.

Comment: Why you would need Windows 7 or Linux Mint to write your keys onto a piece of paper?

Answer (score -1):

There are a few ways that you can create cold storage.

One possibility is to make a new installation of Bitcoin Core on an offline PC, one that is never connected to the internet. This PC will generate addresses and you can add those as a 'watch-only' address on an online PC to monitor incoming payments.

It is possible to update your offline PC, for example, using a `bootstrap.dat` file so that it will have the blockchain without ever needing to connect.

This will work with Windows 7 and any platform where Bitcoin Core can be installed including on several versions of Linux.

Paper wallets do not require a computer until you want to import the keys. You can import the public address as a 'watch-only' address or when you are ready to spend your BTC somewhere, you can import the private key.

Answer (score -1):

Yes, it can for both. Though I am a regular Linux user (I've used Windows before at school and the library), I know that you can store paper wallets. It is easier to do with Linux if you know the command line, though graphic tools can help *a lot*. Copy the  wallet.dat file to a hard drive off of the computer. It is NOT a good idea to keep one private key because you could lose funds, so you should keep the wallet.dat file as a whole.